# Blazor/Electron : Handling close event

Tags: c#, .net, electron, blazor

I have begin experimental application with Blazor/Electron.

I have forked the project :
https://github.com/SteveSandersonMS/BlazorElectronExperiment.Sample

When the application is closed, It need save the application's state.
For this, I think it need handle the close event and save application's state before the final close.

How do handle the close event?
Have you other solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Blazor live cycle](https://blazor.net/docs/components/index.html#lifecycle-methods) don't have any method ready to be called `OnExit`.

An idea may be to [implement IDisposable on your component](https://blazor.net/docs/components/index.html#component-disposal-with-idisposable) and call `saveState` 
 from `Dispose`.

> If a component implements IDisposable, the Dispose method is called when the component is removed from the UI.

```
@using System
@implements IDisposable

...

@functions {
    public void Dispose()
    {
        //anti-pattern work around
        //liveCycle OnUnload don't exists
        save_your_state();
    }
}
```

*Disclaimer: This approach is an anti-pattern and it is just a workaround until a more elegant solution be ready.*

Comment: Nice idea. But Dispose is invoked all time the component end, not when the whole application is closed.

Comment: @Orwel, yes and not. You can create a component ad-hoc, take a look to my [BlazonConfirm](https://github.com/ctrl-alt-d/BlazorConfirm) component. You can write a kind of 'BlazorOnExit' component just making BlazorConfirm disposable.

Comment: BlazorConfirm is a good example to register to specific JS event. But your first answer is more simple and work. It's like save/restore state in Android.

Comment: @Orwel, I have mentioned BlazorConfirm because is a component that is present all the time and dies only one time, on exit app. ( is a reply about  your comment *But Dispose is invoked all time the component end, not when the whole application is closed*, I mean, you can write a component that only Dispose one time, on exit App and BlazorConfirm is a sample of it) Regards